# How to print a content of file slowly or in bulks with delays between

Tags: linux, file, shell, unix, cat

I am developing an application that processes a streaming binary data (using `rtmpdump` with output to STDOUT) during its download. For debugging purpose I would like to replace such stream download with slow printing of local file to STDOUT, so I will process data I know.

Linux command  `cat file.bin` is simple solution, but it is too fast in compare to stream download. The application I am working on with real stream, downloads and processes data in bulks that are much smaller in compare to bulks that I have when `cat` is used instead.

What Linux command should be used to make such print slower? How can I "manage" speed of such print?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small Perl script:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $f, "<", "file.bin" or die($!);
binmode($f);
my $buf;
while(my $len = read($f, $buf, 100 * rand() + 10))
{
    print $buf;
    sleep rand() * 2;
}
close $f;
```

Answer (score 1):

A one-liner which does the same (and better) :

```
perl -ne '$|=1; for (split //) { print; select(undef,undef,undef, 0.07) }' file.txt
```

The 4th argument in the `select()` function:

0.10 – rather slow; 0.07 - rather ok; 0.03 – rather fast

Change it according to your taste.